# What is being displayed when I read a two-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand the way that C handles arrays, in this case, by reading a two-dimensional array as though it were a one-dimensional array.

Given this simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int array[4][4];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            array[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        printf("%d ", array[i]);    
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

I get this strange output.

```
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12 
4 8 12 16 
56319776 56319792 56319808 56319824 56319840 56319856 56319872 56319888 56319904 56319920 56319936 56319952 56319968 56319984 56320000 56320016
```

What is being printed in the second `for` loop?

Comment: Printing the array addresses in the garbage print.

Comment: Isn't this "garbage" actually address (or pointer) to the value stored in? What we'll get if we do `&(array[i])`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is being printed in the second for loop?

Short answer is "it's garbage". The official name for it is "undefined behavior", but it's a essentially you see a sequence of arbitrary decimal digits.

Long answer is a little trickier: you are passing `printf` addresses of one-dimension arrays, which get *re-interpreted* as integer numbers. Note how the numbers are apart by the same step of 16. This is the size of four `int`s on your system.

If you want to get the original numbers through an array of one dimension, you could force a different re-interpretation of the array - as a pointer to `int`:

```
int *ptr = (int*)&array;
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
}
```

This produces the sequence of numbers from your 2D array, the way the array is stored in memory (row-by-row).

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/UVhvXn)

Comment: Does this mean I have created sixteen one by one arrays? I would have thought that I created four one by four arrays, but it seems that the printed result is sixteen different re-interpreted addresses.

Comment: @JoshuaCook No, you created four arrays, 4x1 each. `array[i]` is the address of `i`-th such array. Only the first four addresses are within the array; the remaining 12 are outside the array. However, `printf` does not care, because it prints the address itself, without reading or writing a value at that address.

Comment: So what information am I getting from `array[i]` for `i>3`?

Comment: @JoshuaCook You get the address of a 4x1 array that would have been there if `array` were declared as `array[16][4]` (of course you cannot rely on it being like that on every system, because it's the behavior is undefined).

Comment: @JoshuaCook; Garbage value. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So, I take it from the program you posted on ideone, that the proper way to "walk" through a 2d-array element by element is by using a pointer?

Comment: @JoshuaCook Well, C arrays are to a large extent about pointer arithmetic. Once you know the address of the initial element and the size of a single element, you can compute the address of any element - either a real, valid, address, or a theoretical address, which may or may not be valid. C will convert your array to a pointer "for free", leading people to an incorrect conclusion that arrays are pointers (they are not). The example that I posted on ideone uses a separate pointer to walk the array, but you do not need to declare it explicitly: you could do it with a cast to `int*` as well.

Comment: This example is also UB once `ptr` exceeds the bounds of `array[0]`; to avoid this do `int *ptr = (int *)&array;` or `(int *)array`

Answer (score 4):

2D arrays are thought as 1D array of 1D arrays. It is printing the address of 1D arrays but you should use `%p` specifier to print the address otherwise it invokes **undefined behavior**.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%p", (void *)array[i]);    
}
```

`int array[4][4]` is of type 2D array of 16 integers or you can say that `array` is a 1D array of 4 1D arrays of `int`'s.

You should note that only your program invokes undefined behavior for two reasons:
1. wrong specifier `%d` is used to print address.
2. you are accessing out of bound in your last loop. `for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)` should be `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Comment: Technically you should cast to `void *` or `char *` when using `%p` else the behavior is undefined, although on most platforms it is a no-op.  In practice, nobody cares.

Comment: Thanks for the `%p` specifier.

Comment: I get that I have created a one by four, but shouldn't I then only have four different addresses?